# Official Java compiler

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I googled,I checked wikipedia.None of them helped me to find an official java compiler by Sun.

By "official" I mean for example "C# Express" by Microsoft.I want that type of compiler by Sun.

My question is: Where do I get it?

I'm very sorry for my stupid question,I just get lost when I open java dot com.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: are you sure you mean compiler and not IDE?

Comment: "I'm very sorry for my stupid question,I just get lost when I open java dot com." I know exactly what you mean. If you think that is bad you should try sun.com.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? He got the terms IDE and compiler mixed up, but it's still an excellent question. He wants to know if Sun makes an official IDE, like Microsoft does with their Express products.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

C# Express is an IDE (Integrated Development Environment), not just a compiler.

The JDK ships with `javac` which is the equivalent of `csc` - they're the compilers.

The nearest equivalent to C# Express is probably [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/), although there are other IDEs available for Java, such as [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org) (free) and [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) (not free).

Comment: The easiest is probably Eclipse as it works with the JRE which can be automatically installed by java.com.  Most others need a separate JDK installation.

But then, if you get lost at java.com then Eclipse is probably a bit overwhelming.  I would suggest having a look at The Java Tutorial from Sun.  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/index.html

Comment: Netbeans 6.5.1 bundled with JDK6u13 can be downloaded from: http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/netbeans.html

Comment: The compiler bundled with Eclipse is from IBM's JDK, so you may not realise you are not using Sun's "official" compiler

Answer (score 12):

Official java compiler is bin/javac that comes with Sun's JDK.

http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp (see Java SE Development Kit).
It contains the compiler in question.

Answer (score 6):

I think, based on your mention of Visual C# Express, that what you're looking for is an IDE (integrated development environment), not a compiler as such. Go to http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/ and get the NetBeans bundle.

Answer (score 3):

The `javac` compiler comes as part of the [JDK which you can download here](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp).

You probably want the *Java SE Development Kit* (fourth one down at the time of writing).

Answer (score 3):

The "official" compiler is that which ships with the [Sun Microsystems version of the Java Development Kit](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp).

Since the Java language and platform are fully specified, there are various other implementations of the Java environment; for example, both Oracle and IBM sell products which incorporate their own Java Runtime Environments, etc.

You mentioned "C# Express" in your question, by which I assume you meant the version of Visual Studio Express that supports C#; Visual Studio is an integrated development environment, which provides source code editing, refactoring, and debugging facilities, and interacts with the compiler and build processes on your behalf. If you're looking for an IDE for Java, then you might want to take a look at [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org) (which is sponsored by Sun) or [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org).

Answer (score 2):

http://java.sun.com

Answer (score 2):

Get official compiler/SDK here: http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp

Answer (score 2):

I guess the equivalent to "C# Express" would be [JDK 6u13 with Netbean IDE bundle](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/netbeans.html).

If you don not require an IDE then you can download the standalone [JDK](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp).

Answer (score 0):

There is no official compiler in Java as such. Java is a set of specification driven by community. You can call it just a piece of document. What sun does is that it provides a reference implementation to this document. You can download from the links as given above. You can install Java as mentioned in http://oyejava.com/tiki-index.php?page=Installing+Java

Also you might want to use one of IDE like eclipse or Netbeans for development. For basics of eclipse see at http://oyejava.com/tiki-index.php?page=Eclipse+Download